# using uuid as id/pk in django breaks admin page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

i am using django 1.0.4 and have 3 models: Category <-1-m-> Item <-1-m-> Image.

i recently changed the id/pk to uuid:

```
id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True,
                      default=make_uuid, editable=False)
...
def make_uuid():
    return str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')
```

after i started using uuid, the Item's admin page would no longer let me inline add an Image.  it would give me a form validation error even though there isn't any error.  furthemore, if an Item has an Image, i can't change the Category, it would give me the following error:

```
KeyError at /admin/inventory/item/90965921681b4b69880b36bd716b0831/
id
...
/local/env/bfi2/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.0.4-py2.6.egg/django/forms/forms.py in _raw_value
 213. field = self.fields[fieldname]
```

i think this is similar to the following bug: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10992.  ideally, i would like to avoid upgrading django and just patch the necessary files.  has anyone else ran into this problem?

thanks,
steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone into such problems but they got solved with [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) UUID field.
But I cannot guarantee that this Field will work with an old django version, it was on 1.2.3